# How can I fully duplicate middle click behavior with javascript

Tags: jquery, mouseclick-event

I have a table on my site that has click events on it's  tags, so they act like links. I'm trying to properly duplicate the middle click event so it acts the same way as normal  links.

I have it opening up a new tab when I middle click, but I want to get the new tab to pop under rather than pop up (ie not take focus).

Is there a way to do this?

Here's some sample code ofr what I have working at the moment

```
<script type="text/javascript">
urlTemplate = '/library/edit/ID';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.row_link').mousedown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $('.row_link').mouseup(function(e){
        url = urlTemplate.replace('ID',$(this).attr('rel'));
        if(e.which === 1) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            document.location.href=url;
        }
        else if(e.which === 2) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
            window.open(url);
        }
    });
});
</script>

...

<table id="document-index">
    <tr class="row_link" rel="4004">
        <td>IBTAKTF.pdf</td>
        <td>blah, blah, blah</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#button for some pointers regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
window.focus();
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_focus.asp